# SOLR FTS Status meaning

Tags: solr, alfresco

Can anyone tell me what the status values for the FTS Status report mean.

In particular what does FTS Status Clean and FTS Status New mean for a core.

Regards

Brian

Comment: Hi Brian, please don't forget to react to the answers given, provided that you are still active on SO...

Answer (score 1):

Solr is available to support search within the Alfresco repository.
The existing embedded Lucene index will continue to be available in alfresco versions.

please find this [documentation](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6064-alfresco-and-solr)
to get more details about alfresco-solr report

Answer (score 1):

**FTS** means "Full Text Search" in Alfresco / Solr terms. And the **FTS Status Report** at the [Solr webapp](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/solradmin-left.html) seems to display number of Alfresco nodes whose text content: 1) was successfully indexed (FTS Status Clean), 2) is waiting to be indexed (FTS Status New).

Note that when you open the XML report whose URL (*/solr4/admin/cores?action=SUMMARY&wt=xml*) is linked from the "Summary Report", you can also find "Approx content indexing time remaining" which correlates with the "FTS Status New", but it isn't displayed in the GUI (for whatever reason).

Comment: BTW There seems to be no documentation for this, I've got the information just from a practical experience.